# norm bounded Convolution in matrix space

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, convolution

There is a stable matrix $A$ with eigen values in unit circle,for discrete time system :
$x(k+1)=Ax(k)+f(k)$ can we prove:
$||\Sigma_{j=0,..,k} A^{k-j}f(j)||_2<= ||f(k)||_2/{(1-A_{max})} $ where $A_{max}=Max(eig(A))$

Comment: I don't think that you can prove this. I think that in the expression $\|f(k)\|_2/(1-A_{max})$ on the r.h.s., you have to replace $\|f(k)\|_2$ with $\max_{0 \leq j \leq k}\|f(j)\|.$

Comment: does it mean : $||f(k)||_{\inf}$ ?